# Failed to fetch resource hooks to invoke for the resource in aws cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, installation, pipeline, aws-cdk, rollback

when i am doing cdk deploy it is giving this result

CsSubscriptionClassifierStack: creating CloudFormation changeset...
12:31:10 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::S3::Bucket             | SubscriptionClassi...lassifiers4A6AE16E
cs-subscription-classifiers already exists

12:31:11 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::CDK::Metadata          | CDKMetadata
Failed to fetch resource hooks to invoke for the resource

❌  CsSubscriptionClassifierStack failed: Error: The stack named CsSubscriptionClassifierStack failed creation, it may need to be manually deleted from the AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE
at Object.waitForStackDeploy (/mnt/c/Users/Vishnu Kumar Gupta/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/util/cloudformation.ts:307:11)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at prepareAndExecuteChangeSet (/mnt/c/Users/Vishnu Kumar Gupta/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/deploy-stack.ts:355:26)
at CdkToolkit.deploy (/mnt/c/Users/Vishnu Kumar Gupta/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:201:24)
at initCommandLine (/mnt/c/Users/Vishnu Kumar Gupta/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cli.ts:314:21)
The stack named CsSubscriptionClassifierStack failed creation, it may need to be manually deleted from the AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/req19.png)

Comment: Please edit your question with additional context.  Has the stack been deployed previously?  What is the CDK code (add a minimal example)?   Also, please avoid images of code.

Comment: the error message from cdk deploy unfortunately is not a great one.

If you go to your console > CloudFormation > Stacks - set the status to Deleted > look for your stack > Events  -- you can get a better idea of what caused the actual failure (sometimes) - posting that can give us here more info to help